# How can I overwrite an item pointed by the index of a vector?

Tags: c++, vector, indexing, std

I would like to overwrite an item pointed by index even if that index doesn't exist yet. operator[] works up until it is not out of bound. emplace seems to do this, but it need an iterator for the first param. I could use myvector.begin()+index but it's invalid when the vector is empty.

Clarification. My current implementation:

```
while (index < myvector.size())
    myvector.push_back("");

myvector[index] = val;
```

I was hoping for an std method. The array is always very small (few elements).

Using the accepted answer, my code changes to:

```
if (index >= myvector.size()) // to avoid destroying the remaining elements when the index is smaller than current size
    myvector.resize(index+1);
myvector[index] = val;
```

Comment: Clarification needed. If index does not exist, create index? If so, `vector` will have to create all of the missing elements between the last and this new element. Consider using a `std::map` instead.

Comment: How can you overwrite an item that doesn't exist?  AFAIK, items must exist to be *overwritten*.

Comment: Now that you have edited your question, nothing makes sense.

Comment: A few people have mentioned "undefined behaviour."  That is definitely worth noting because you are using operator[] instead of at().  Consider changing to at() until you are sure that your code is working.  That way you will have the benefit of a bounds check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To *overwrite* an element of given index, that index must be inside *valid* vector bounds.

You can set the size of your vector to whatever value using `vector::resize`, and just use `operator[]` with indexes in the range `[0, size-1]`:

```
std::vector<std::string> data;
...
data.resize(100);
// Use data[i] for i = 0,1,2,...99
```

Comment: Not `if (data.size() < 100) data.resize(100)`?

Comment: @ilotXXI: I'm not sure what exact logic the OP is implementing. I wrote _"whatever value [of size]"_... I don't know when/how the OP wants to resize.